# What is the opposite of the expression "have nothing to do with"?

Tags: expressions, idioms

Example: A policeman found a pack of cocaine next to me, but I told him that drug **had nothing to do with** me. What I mean is: I was not connected to the cocaine at all.

On the other hand, my friend Charles (***place the opposite expression here***).

What expression is the opposite to "have nothing to do with", considering that my friend is connected to the drug somehow?

Edit: since my first example was a misconception from what I was trying to ask, I brought another context. The asnwers given helped me understand another definition, though. Thanks to everyone who pointed out I was wrong and to those who answered before this edit and helped me anyway.

Comment: [**Have in common**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+in+common) is just perfect here

Comment: @NVZ, but, won't there be an opposite to "have to do with"? Like, "she has everything to do with me", maybe? Because I already know the expression "to have in common with", so I'd rather have a new and extra expression/idiom to improve my vocabulary, you know.

Comment: **Have a lot to do with**

Comment: Your premise is flawed:  "has nothing to do with" does not mean "has nothing in common with".

Comment: @hellion is exactly right. And if question was opposite of  *.. nothing in common ...* then it would be  *... lots in common ...*

Comment: Probably from Portuguese: não ter nada a ver com, which has been translated literally as have nothing to do with. When the actual translation is: to have nothing in common with, as people have been pointing out....English language learner question?

Comment: had everything to do with it.

Answer (score 3):

My friend's sister and I **share a great affinity**.

> - **affinity** - A natural attraction, liking, or feeling of kinship, a natural compatibility of one thing with another. [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/affinity)

affinity may be followed by **of**, **between**, or **with**.

e.g.

The two of us share a great affinity.

I admire the close affinity of/between Rose and Pam.

I have a special affinity with dogs.

**EDIT - Inasmuch as the OP has been changed, I feel I have to provide another answer.**

> **"On the other hand, my friend Charles was involved."**
>
> [**Involved**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/involved) -  connected by participation or association: e.g. He was involved in a conspiracy.

Comment: You helped understand another definition, man. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

*Have nothing to do with* means not having an interaction with.  I think you mean what you said --- you have nothing in common -- i.e, you share no background, interests, or experience.  You may share no interests with someone with whom you deal with every day.  For this person who is easy to get along with because you share so much, you may say

> My friend's sister and I are **[simpatico](https://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/simpatico)**.

Answer (score 0):

In your particular example, I think **implicated** works well.

> - **implicated** -  show (someone) to be involved in a crime

But in the absence of a criminal aspect, I think Centaurus answer of **involved** works better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to give you some options:

- Be heavily involved in.
- Have a big influence over.
- Play a major/large role in.
- Have much to do with.

The last one, I believe it's grammatically correct; however, it still doesn't sound natural to me.